# Error when reading JSON from S3 using the JavaScript aws-sdk

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

Here's my little node.js app:

```
var http = require("http");
var url = require("url");
var aws = require("aws-sdk");
aws.config.region = "us-east-1";


http.createServer(function(request, response) {
    params = url.parse(request.url, true)["query"];
    var req_body = "";

    request.on("data", function(chunk) {
        req_body += chunk;
    })

    request.on("end", function() {
        fileName = params["file"];
        s3 = new aws.S3();
        s3.getObject(
            {"Bucket": "my_bucket", "Key": fileName},
            function(error, data) {
                fileJSON = data["Body"].toString();
                response.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
                response.end(fileJSON);
            }
        );
    });
}).listen(8080);
```

I ran this app and submitted a GET request with URL parameter `file=my_file.json`.  The app returned the JSON and my browser correctly parsed it - everything was great!

The problem?  Immediately after returning the data the app crashed and threw the error

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'Body' of null`

on the line `fileJSON = data["Body"].toString();`.  This might have made sense if the app had failed to return any data, but in fact it returned the *correct* data and *then* crashed.  I'm still pretty new to node.js, but this behavior seems utterly bizarre.  Any ideas?

---

After running a few experiments (as suggested in the comments) it turns out that when I submit a GET request of the form `127.0.0.1:8080/?file=my_file_json` the browser makes two requests, one where `params` is `{"file": "my_file.json"}` as expected and one where `params` is empty.  Why are two requests happening?  Why is one of them empty?

Comment: May be you requested your server twice - once with a file name and the other time without it? Check `error` that is returned by `getObject`

Comment: @VsevolodGoloviznin You were right: the server is getting two requests, first with the `params` object equal to `{"file": "my_file.json"}` and then equal to `{}`.  So I guess the heart of the question is: why are both requests happening?  I'm just submitting a GET request by running the app locally and visiting `127.0.0.1:8080/?file=my_file.json` in my browser.

Comment: It can request `favicon.ico` and that's why it's hitting the method again